# Use pushed branch name in gitlab-ci script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have this gitlab-ci script that run on branch with the prefix `staging-` using regex and command in the script that checkout to the pushed branch. How can I use the pushed branch name in the script? I tried using the same regex and the job failed.

```
deploy:
  tags:
    - server
  only:
    - /^staging-.*$/
  script:
    - cd /var/www/project
    - sudo git reset --hard HEAD
    - sudo git clean -fd
    - sudo git checkout /^staging-.*$/
    - sudo git pull origin /^staging-.*$/
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a bit reading in Gitlab docs, I found that using predefined variables works best.

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

```
deploy:
  tags:
    - server
  only:
    - /^staging-.*$/
  script:
    - cd /var/www/project
    - sudo git reset --hard HEAD
    - sudo git clean -fd
    - sudo git checkout ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    - sudo git pull origin ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
```